# Getting Http code 400 while calling MS Graph API from console based java application to read excel file stored in onedrive

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

I am trying to read an Excel file stored in my onedrive through microsoft graph api . For this in this console based application i provided my tenant id , client secret & client id which i generated through Microsoft azure console .Through post api i passed those information with the authentication URL but whenever i am running the code i am getting status code 400 which means bad request.  Why it returning 400 status code ? Any error in my approach ?

Code :

Authenticator.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.IAuthenticationProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.http.IHttpRequest;

public class Authenticator {
    
    public final static String clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public final static String clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public final static String tenant = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    
    
    
    private String grantType = "client_credentials";
    private String tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" +tenant + "/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    private String scope = "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default";
    private String accessToken = null;

    protected IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = null;

    public Authenticator() { }
    
    public IAuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        if (authenticationProvider == null) {
            try {
                System.out.println(accessToken);
                accessToken = getAccessToken().replace("\"", "");
                System.out.println(accessToken);
                authenticationProvider = new IAuthenticationProvider() {
                    public void authenticateRequest(final IHttpRequest request) {
                        request.addHeader("Authorization",
                                "Bearer " + accessToken);
                    }
                };

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Error("Could not create authentication provider: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    private String getAccessToken()
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(tokenEndpoint);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String line;
            StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            conn.connect();
            String secret = clientSecret.replace("+", "%2B").replace("=", "%3D").replace("/", "%2F");
            
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            String payload = String.format("grant_type=%1$s&scope=%2$s&client_id=%3$s&client_secret=%4$s",
                    grantType,
                    scope,
                    clientId,
                    secret);
            writer.write(payload);
            writer.close();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    jsonString.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Error("Error reading authorization response: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            conn.disconnect();

            JsonObject res = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonString.toString(), JsonObject.class);
            return res.get("access_token").toString().replaceAll("\"", "");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Error("Error retrieving access token: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

ReadExcel.java

```
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.IAuthenticationProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.IGraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.WorkbookRange;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.GraphServiceClient;

public class ReadExcel {
    
    public static IGraphServiceClient graphClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
        IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = authenticator
                .getAuthenticationProvider();
       
        
        IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authenticationProvider ).buildClient();

        WorkbookRange workbookRange = graphClient.me().drive().items("XXXXXXXXXX").workbook().worksheets("Sheet1")
            .range("A1:B2")
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
        

    }

}
```

Error :
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/oauth2/v2.0/token

Example code to authenticate graph api will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

### Update-1:

Updated the code and Used "oauth2-oidc-sdk" for authentication. Updated my code  as described in Micrsoft Graph tutorial sample code.
Github Link : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-java-connect-sample

But got this error -

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: c77ba129-89ec-4869-993d-55475fab4800\r\nCorrelation ID: 34ce3c6b-b125-4c24-b57f-9716f320462c\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-16 06:18:36Z","error_codes":[9002313],"timestamp":"2020-09-16 06:18:36Z","trace_id":"c77ba129-89ec-4869-993d-55475fab4800","correlation_id":"34ce3c6b-b125-4c24-b57f-9716f320462c","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"}

Comment: Capture the full request of getting access token and share it.

Comment: Could you please share the HTTP call that is happening from your application to token endpoint with the parameters by tracking with Fiddler?